# Get how long device on hold state in call

Tags: asterisk, channel, pjsip, bridge

Is there a way to get the value of how long the extension `on hold` state when call is happen ? I know there is `rtp_holdtimeout` in pjsip context option endpoints type, but i need only the value without having hangup the extension. Thank

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each hold produce event on start/stop.

You have read events via AMI Events routine, record for this call ID all start/stop and calculate.

No, it is not doable without external program.